# Inserting data to database returning as <br /> <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am having a problem whenever I execute the submit of the form to the database. It does submit the data to the form but it is an error instead of the data that was inserted.
**index.php**

```
<div id="postForm">
    <!-- Username of the user posting the Language Learning Object -->
    <div id="postUserName" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="Username of user">Username of user </label>
        <input type="text" name="post_username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['post_username']; ?>" readonly="readonly" id="post_username"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Word of the language learning object -->
    <div id="postWord" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="Word for Language Learning Object">Word for Language Learning Object </label>
        <input type="text" name="post_word" id="post_word" />
    </div>

    <!-- Description of the word -->
    <div id="postDescription" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="Word description">Word description </label>
        <textarea name="word_description" id="word_description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Categorization of the given word -->
    <div id="postCategorization" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="Categorization of Word">Categorization of Word </label>
        <select name="word_categorization" id="word_categorization">
            <option value=""> Select </option>
            <option value="Adverb"> Adverb </option>
            <option value="Adjective"> Adjective </option>
            <option value="Noun"> Noun </option>
            <option value="Verb"> Verb </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Origin of the given word -->
    <div id="postOrigin" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="Origin of Word">Origin of Word </label>
        <input type="text" name="word_origin" id="word_origin" />
    </div>

    <!-- Getting the user's location -->
    <div id="userLocation" data-role="field-contain">
        <label for="user location">User location</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_loc" value="<?php echo $geo->city;?>" />
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div id="submitPost" data-role="field-contain">
        <button name="submit_post" type="submit" id="submit_post">Create post</button>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of Form -->
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

include_once( 'connect.php' );

class ManagePost {

    protected $link;

    /* Connection to database */
    function __construct(){
        $db_connect = new ManageDatabase;
        $this->link = $db_connect->databaseconnect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    /* creating language learning objects/posts */
    function addPost($username,$word,$description,$categorization,$origin,$user_loc,$date,$time) {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO post (username, word, description, categorization, origin, user_loc, date, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $values = array($username,$word,$description,$categorization,$origin,$user_loc,$date,$time);

        $query->execute($values);
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();

        return $rowCount;
    }
}
```

**dbpost.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include('../class/post.php');
    $post_init = new ManagePost;

    if($_POST)
    {
        $username           = $_POST['post_username'];
        $word               = $_POST['post_word'];
        $description        = $_POST['word_description'];
        $categorization     = $_POST['word_categorization'];
        $origin             = $_POST['word_origin'];
        $user_loc           = $_POST['user_loc'];
        $date               = date("Y-M-D");
        $time               = date ("H:i:s");

        $submit_post = $post_init->addPost($username, $word, $description, $categorization, $origin, $user_loc, $date, $time);

        if($submit_post == 1)
        {
            echo 'true';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'failed to submit';
        }
    }
?>
```

**createpost.js**

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    if(validateWord() && validateDescription() && validateCategorization() &&  validateOrigin())
    {
        $.post('lib/dbpost.php', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
            if(response == 'true')
            {
                showSuccess('Post submitted');
            }
            else
            {
                showError(response);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

When I check the table post in phpMyAdmin it just shows as errors like this

```
<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe
```

in the attributes

```
"word, description, origin, and user_loc"
```

Comment: It would be really handy to see that actual error message

Comment: The errors gets inserted in the table instead of the data input. I am trying to find out why it keeps giving me that error instead of the text inserted in the fields.

Comment: Change the column to text instead of varchar so that the xdebug error is not truncated then you can read it all and see what the error message really is. Must say I am surprised at this, xdebug should normally terminate the script.

Comment: Ah, I bet it's one of your pre-populated input values. Make sure you use `htmlspecialchars` for any `value` attributes, eg `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($geo->city) ?>"`. Same goes for `$_SESSION['post_username']`. Check the rendered HTML (as in *View Source*) for your form before it's submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the add_post function as shown below:

```
function addPost($username, $word, $description, $categorization, $origin, $user_loc, $date,$time){
    $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO post (username,word,description,categorization,origin,user_loc,date,time)
    VALUES (:username,:word,:description,:categorization,:origin,:user_loc,:date,:time)");
    $query->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $query->bindParam(':word', $word);
    $query->bindParam(':description', $description);
    $query->bindParam(':categorization', $categorization);
    $query->bindParam(':origin', $origin);
    $query->bindParam(':user_loc', $user_loc);
    $query->bindParam(':date', $date);
    $query->bindParam(':time', $time);
    $query->execute();
    $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $rowCount;
}
```

Comment: It still updates the table but still shows me the error, the only actual text that the form takes is the username, time, and date. As for the rest of the tables it gives me this results "<br /><font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe"

Comment: Are you getting all the POST variables there?